# add to an integer variable after comparing two arrays

Tags: php, arrays, loops, listbox

I am fairly new to php.  I am trying to update the score everytime I loop over this array.  my code only works if the first value of the listbox was selected by the user and it gives a zero if its not selected. please help. 
This is A.php

```
{
    $SkillsArray = array();
    $Score=0;
    $SkillsArray = $_POST['DutiesDesc'];
    //foreach($SkillsArray as $key =>$value )
    {
        $Sentence = $SkillsArray[0]." ".$SkillsArray[1]." ".$SkillsArray[2]." ".$SkillsArray[3]." ".$SkillsArray[4]." ".$SkillsArray[5]." ".$SkillsArray[6]." ".$SkillsArray[7                              ]." ".$SkillsArray[8]." ".$SkillsArray[9]." ".$SkillsArray[10];
    }

        //Get the applicants score
        for($i=0;$i<11;$i++)
            {
                if ($SkillsArray[$i] == $Text[$i])
                    {
                        $Score = $Score+$Val[$i];
                    }
            }

} //**** The following is the HTML part of the code(form)
<form action = "A.php" method ="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="Position">Position:</label><input type="type" name="Position" size="35" /><br />
                      </p>
                      <p>
                        <!-- <label for="DutiesDesc">Duties Description:&nbsp;</label><textarea name="DutiesDesc" cols="30" rows="5" /></textarea>--> <br />
                        Job Description
                        <select name="DutiesDesc[]" size=5 multiple="multiple">

                            <option value="<?php echo $Arow['TextF1']?>"><?php echo $Arow['TextF1']?></option>
                            <option value="<?php echo $Arow['TextF2']?>"><?php echo $Arow['TextF2']?></option>
                            <option value="<?php echo $Arow['TextF3']?>"><?php echo $Arow['TextF3']?></option>
                            <option value="<?php echo $Arow['TextF4']?>"><?php echo $Arow['TextF4']?></option>
                            <option value="<?php echo $Arow['TextF5']?>"><?php echo $Arow['TextF5']?></option>
                            <option value="<?php echo $Arow['TextF6']?>"><?php echo $Arow['TextF6']?></option>
                            <option value="<?php echo $Arow['TextF7']?>"><?php echo $Arow['TextF7']?></option>
                            <option value="<?php echo $Arow['TextF8']?>"><?php echo $Arow['TextF8']?></option>
                            <option value="<?php echo $Arow['TextF9']?>"><?php echo $Arow['TextF9']?></option>
                            <option value="<?php echo $Arow['TextF10']?>"><?php echo $Arow['TextF10']?></option>
                            <option value="<?php echo $Arow['TextF11']?>"><?php echo $Arow['TextF11']?></option>

                        </select><br />
```

Comment: What are the option values? Numbers? Or Text? Does `$Arow[]` contain the same values as `$Text[]`? Also you can try to debug your code by `print_r($SkillsArray);` in your A.php to find out the exact content of this variable and help you to understand, why somethings not working as expected. If my assumptions are correct your code might very well be correct.

Comment: Hi Peter. SkillsArray contains Text.  Option Values are Texts retrieved from the database. Yes, $Arow[] and $Text[] contains the same data(Text).

Comment: When I select all other options excluding $Arow['TextF1'] the $Score variable doesnt get updated. its like it doesnt get into the for loop. but it works fine if I select options including $Arow['TextF1']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values in the array `$SkillsArray` do not have the same index as your `$Text` array. If you select the 3rd (lets say the value is "c") and 5th (e.g. "e") item in your list, the array `$SkillsArray` will contain the following:

```
$SkillsArray[0] = "c";
$SkillsArray[1] = "e";
```

So what you need is a simple search over your `$SkillsArray`, since you can't rely on the indexes being conform with your `$Text` array.

```
if (is_array($SkillsArray)) {
  for($i = 0; $i < count($Text); $i++) {
    if (array_search($Text[$i], $SkillsArray) !== false) {
      $Score += $Val[$i];
    }
  }
}
```

Please do remember to check, if `$SkillsArray` is indeed an array. If the user doesn't check any skills, the function `array_search` will return `false` for every item, which will result in the maximum score.

Documentation for functions: [count](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php), [array_search](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php), [is_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php)
The

Comment: Thank Peter. You were really helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i=0;$i<11;$i++)
            {
                for($j=0;$j<11;$j++) 
                    {
                        if (($SkillsArray[$i] == $Text[$j]))
                            {
                                $Score = $Score+$Val[$j];


                            }
                    }
```

This required a second loop in order to work properley:)